# How to Debug tests in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, testing

Is there a way to debug a single test in angular? For example: I created a simple service called test-service. A Simple test-service.spec.ts file created automatically with a test inside. 
I can call ng test an everything works fine. 
But how can i set a breakpoint inside that spec.ts file? 
I try to do it with Protractor, but if run the test I get this error:

> E/launcher - Error: Error: Cannot find module...

Im using intellij as ide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `Protractor` is for end to end tests.

To debug a single test, change `it` to `fit` or if you want to run the suite change `describe` to `fdescribe`.

You can do `console` debugging by using `console.log` and seeing the terminal. If an instance of a browser opens when you do `ng test`, then if you put `debugger;` in an `it` test it should get tripped (open the developer tools quickly). If you are running headless (no browser opens), you can modify your `karma.conf.js` to open a browser for tests.